# How to convert a jupyter notebook to a python script without cell notation?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to save the Jupyter Notebooks as a `.py` script but when I do it still keeps the cell notation, for example `# In[81]`.

The problem is VS Code still recognizes this as a cell, so I can't run it like a script. How do I save the notebooks as a script but without the cell notations?

I've already tried:

1. file -> download as -> Python(.py)
2. Using `nbconvert` - I get the same result

In command I tried `nbconvert`:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to python example.ipynb
```

I still get a `.py` script with cells.

Comment: This probably isn't the best approach, but you could just merge your cells and then copy + paste into a clean .py file.

Comment: If you download it as (.py) it adds the cell notations as comments (with '#'). So you can run it as a script using the terminal. I don't know vscode, but it shouldn't change its bahaviour based on comments. Maybe there is an option to change vscode's behaviour in the configurations?

Comment: [Jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) allows setting `cell_markers`, see that term on [this page](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats.html#the-percent-format) to get a sense. As it has a lot of power, exemplified [here](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html) it is a good tool to have in your toolbox for working with notebooks. Also nbformat is good to know about because you can customize your own parsing of a notebook because it has the concepts and abstractions of notebooks baked in, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74379308/8508004.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a short python script to parse out the cell notation blocks and substitute them for empty strings. For example:

```py
import re #python regular expression matching module
with open('downloaded_py_file.py', 'r') as f_orig:
    script = re.sub(r'# In\[.*\]:\n','', f_orig.read())
with open('out_file.py','w') as fh:
    fh.write(script)
```

Still download the file as a .py file first. This code will save the file as a script without the cell notation blocks.

Hope this helps!