# Can I parse the content of a Jupyter Notebook cells in a script?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert, papermill

Is it possible to extract the content of a Jupyter notebook input cell programatically? Be that raw cell / code / Markdown, does not matter really. I was thinking of tools like `nbconvert` or `papermill` but could not find exactly what I am looking for... I would like to write a script which will essentially parse a notebook...

Is is possible to parse the output cells too?

Comment: The notebook format is just JSON, so yes, it's possible.

Comment: This is possible. In fact, jupyter/python does it every time it opens a notebook. See [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/nbformat.html) for the format spec of the notebook files. I note that this is much easier to parse if you make and open a simple notebook file at the same time and compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jupyter ecosystem includes **nbformat** for this this task.

The intro at the top of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244733/8508004) will probably help you see how nbformat is the tool you seek. Importantly, the abstractions of the notebook & cells & types of cells is all baked in so that you don't have to worry about json parsing really.

I have an answer that includes code that does this for the text in code cells programmatically [in reply to a post entitled 'How to copy multiple input cells in Jupyter Notebook'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78123424/8508004).

I have several additional examples with code among questions/answers linked [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/search?q=%40fomightez%20nbformat) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a8508004%20nbformat).