# How to convert a jupyter notebook to a python script with cell delimiters (#%%)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How to convert a jupyter notebook to a python script with cell delimiters (#%%)?
I've already checked [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#convert-notebook) , but it doesn't seem to have the one. Also, [the same question found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102245/how-to-convert-a-jupyter-notebook-to-a-python-script-without-cell-notation), the answer doesn't satisfy the need because actual raw source codes of jupyter notebook isn't structured as such. (It'd be better to be able to convert at once, instead of converting with nbconvert first and then pattern matching)

Any tools recommended? Or could you share a script to achieve this?

Comment: VSCode's Jupyter extension from MS has the ability to export a py file from an ipynb file. If that would help.

Comment: @JonSG Thank you for your help! I found the option, and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks similar to [the percent delimiter](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats.html#the-percent-format) that Jupytext handles, see the [top few commands here](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html#command-line-conversion) also. The specific commands I'm referencing:

```bash
jupytext --to py:percent notebook.ipynb         # convert notebook.ipynb to a .py file in the double percent format
jupytext --to py:percent --opt comment_magics=false notebook.ipynb   # same as above + do not comment magic commands
```

See the bottom of [the percent format section](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats.html#the-percent-format) for more about that last command and further customization options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it out the command you shared, and it works!